# Shir Hashirim - when there is no Shabbos Chol HaMoed Pesach

Tags: shabbat, passover, eretz-yisrael, shir-hashirim

Usually Shir HaShirim is said on Shabbos Chol Hamoed Pesach. This year where there is no Shabbos Chol Hamoed the Minhag in Chutz L'Aretz is to read it on Shabbos Achron Shel Pesach. In Eretz Yisroel where there is no Shabbos Chol Hamoed Pesach and no Shabbos Achron Shel Pesach, when is it read? Is it read on the first day of Pesach or some other time?

Comment: anecdotally (I have no sources other than the http://www.ttidbits.com/995/995XL.pdf), some shuls in Israel read it on the first day which is shabbat pesach, and some don't read it at all.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/666

Comment: My teimoni shul reads it every 3arav shabboth n on shabboth and 3arav Yom tov n on Yom tov. Basically we read it before most non 7ol tafilloth.

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov A lot of people do that privately. Does your shul read it in public?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Nit'ei Gavriel (Pesach 108:5)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46448&pgnum=581) states, as Dan mentioned in his comment, that in Eretz Yisrael in such a case they read it on the first day of Pesach, and in chutz la'aretz they do so on the eighth day.

Comment: The same would apply IIRC to first day of sukkot on shabbat. In chu"l they read kohelet on shemini atzeret; in Israel when that is simchat torah, they read kohelet on the first day.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why don't they read Kohellet on Simchat Torah in Israel? Too much to do in one day?

Comment: @DanF either that or because in the Diaspora we still sit in the Sukkah on the 8th day so it's connected to Sukkot, but in Israel there's no connection left on day 8 to Sukkot.