# There is no Shabbat Chol Hamoed for Sukkot this year. Why is Kohelet not read on the same day in both E"Y and chu"l?

Tags: sukkot, kohelet, minhagim

I can understand why Kohelet is not read on Shmini Atzeret in E"Y, because it's already a long davening. However, why doesn't everyone read it on the first day of the chag, which is also Shabbat?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) elshpen and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This was not always the custom, see https://schechter.edu/why-and-when-do-we-read-the-book-of-kohelet-ecclesiastes-in-public-responsa-in-a-moment-volume-1-issue-no-2-october-2006-orah-hayyim-6632-1/ and https://hakirah.org/Vol23Ron.pdf (p. 275)

Comment: https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&p=809778

Comment: The question is really the other way round though. The Ashkenazi custom appears to have developed in ChuL. So the question is why it got swapped from shmini atzeret to first day sukkot when ashkenazim came back to Israel.

Comment: "Kohelet is not read on Shmini Atzeret in E"Y, because it's already a long davening", who says that's the reason?

Comment: @robev agree - I would rather argue it doesn't fit the joyous mood of the day

Comment: @mbloch Yizkor? Geshem?

Comment: @JoelK I hear you but I'm just saying the fact the tefila is long is not a reason to exclude Kohelet. There are other long tefilot in the year. The somber mood of Kohelet vs. the joy of Simchat Torah strikes me as much more compelling

Comment: I don't think it's any of the reasons given. In Israel the eighth day has no sukkah. We read kohelet on sukkot, and in the diaspora the eight day still has a sukkah. cc @mbloch

Comment: Well really JoelK is correct and the Ashkenazi olim were just making up a new minhag when they came. The idea that simchas torah was already too busy is probably sufficient to explain their decision, and any technical justifications are likely post facto.

Comment: Note there's also a parallel difference on pesach https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15529/759